# OnMouseOver / OnMouseOut

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onmouseover, onmouseout

I'm using the onMouseOver and onMouseOut function to change the colour of some social media icons in the footer of my Wordpress website: http://www.retelevise.com.

It works fine, but I'm also using a snippet of Javascript for the link to my email address (I read somewhere this is a good way to hide the address from spammers?) – but the Javascript doesn’t seem to like the mouse function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var addr1 = "mailto:"
var addr2 = "info"
var addr3 = "@"
var addr4 = "retelevise"
var addr5 = ".com"
document.write('<a href="' + addr1 + addr2 + addr3 + addr4 + addr5 + '">')
document.write('<img src="http://www.retelevise.com/wp-content/themes/myownzee/branding/socialmedia-email-1.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.retelevise.com/wp-content/themes/myownzee/branding/socialmedia-email-2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.retelevise.com/wp-content/themes/myownzee/branding/socialmedia-email-1.png'" class="social-icons-main" title="Email" alt="Email"></a>'); 
//-->
</script>
```

If I remove the mouse function, only the grey email icon appears without switching to the color version on hover, but when I try adding the mouse code, the email icon disappears altogether. I did look at some similar answers posted here, but sorry I didn't understand them. Does anybody have any ideas, please?

Thanks,
SN.

Comment: Apart from the fact that using document.write is a bad idea, you are not escaping the `'` at `this.src'`. Your have a piece of code like: `document.write('...onmouseover="this.src'your string ends here)` I'm not even sure what happens to the rest of what you wrote, javascript will probably throw 14 errors at you.

You should escape the `'` characters with `\'`

Comment: It seems you have a little mix up with all the " and 's, 

If you use single quotes for the encapsulation, use double quotes for what's inside and vice verca(that's my rule of thumb).

If you'll open the console, I'm pretty sure your browser will scream at you some JS errors :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no escaping of single quotes used within a single quoted value.

http://jsbin.com/nakoduqa/1/edit

```
var addr1 = "mailto:"
var addr2 = "info"
var addr3 = "@"
var addr4 = "retelevise"
var addr5 = ".com"
document.write('<a href="' + addr1 + addr2 + addr3 + addr4 + addr5 + '">')
document.write('<img src="http://www.retelevise.com/wp-content/themes/myownzee/branding/socialmedia-email-1.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'http://www.retelevise.com/wp-content/themes/myownzee/branding/socialmedia-email-2.png\'" onmouseout="this.src=\'http://www.retelevise.com/wp-content/themes/myownzee/branding/socialmedia-email-1.png\'" class="social-icons-main" title="Email" alt="Email"></a>');
```

Comment: Thank you everybody - you're the best. And melc, I just copied and pasted your code and it works perfectly. Thanks again!